# Is object casting a good practice?

Tags: design-patterns, casting

Object oriented programming languages e.g. java, c#, ... support object typecasting. For example this is perfectly valid in java:

```
URL url = new URL("url");    
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

if( !conn instanceof HttpURLConnection )
  throw new Exception("not http request");

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
```

Or another basic example which I tried:

```
public class Base
{
  public void base(){}
}

public class Derived extends Base
{
  public void derived(){}
}

Base b = new Derived();
b.base();
```

Derived class has all the methods base class has, plus more. There is no reason why you can’t create base class by calling derived class constructor.

I also came across this link http://www.volantec.biz/castingObjects.htm which explains how object typecasting works internally. So far, ok.

But why the first example doesn't use `HttpURLConnection con = new HttpURLConnection("url address")` (I know [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is an abstract class). It just seems more clear, more simple. On the other hand when you are dealing with [interfaces, object typecasting comes in handy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961450/what-is-interface-casting-for-in-c/20374230#20374230). Another example is `List<Object>` list, which I see sometimes in some classes. It means that you can save every possible class in this list. Afterwards you can just cast it to its original, if you know what type it is. Wouldn't it be more clear to save only specific classes to list i.e. `List<String>`, `List<MyClass>`. Is using `List<Object>` good design practise then at all?

Comment: Mandatory casting to `HttpURLConnection` is a perfect example of bad OOD. Regarding the generic lists: it depends, but I would rather go for parameterized-as-much-as-possible lists, so I could catch a lot of runtime type cast exceptions at compile time.

Comment: Well, the answer is in the question: HttpUrlConnection is an abstract class, so you can't create an instance of HttpUrlConnection. Only of a subclass. And that's what url.openConnection() does.

Comment: @JBNizet I mentioned that in brackets. I'm aware that HttpURLConnection is an abstract class, therefore you can't create an instance like you mentioned. You are right, I just wanted to demonstrate it, maybe some other example is more appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

When designing a class hierarchy, you always have to keep the [Liskov's Substitution Principle (aka, LSP)](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html) in mind:

> Derived types must be completely substitutable for their base types.

In other words, to decide whether you should extend a class, you should ask yourself if the components that depends on your new class would be well served if you change it to its base class.

The problem with casting is that if you ever need it to convert a Base class object into a Derived class one, it means you are violating the LSP.

If you need to make sure that an object is from an specific implementation when you are expecting an interface, then there surely is something wrong with your design.

Interfaces are like contracts. If you are using a method of the implementation that is not in the interface, it means you are breaking that contract, creating coupling between your code and a implementation.

Remember that your code should always [rely on abstractions rather than concretions](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DependencyInversionPrinciple).

Comment: If there is a vehicle class which is the base class for TwoWheeler and FourWheeler class,  and suppose in other class we create a List<Vehicle> where we can add both child classes instances as elements, so if there we need to access child class properties and we use Type casting there, will it be a bad design then? Please answer.

Answer (score 0):

by casting with the Object class u r basically giving every available permission to the derived classes, that is  a function will never reject the upcoming parameters, since u have provided that the Object will be accessed so it's dangerous,
and as per @Henrique is saying it is right that  If you need to make sure that an object is a specific implementation when you are expecting an interface, then there surely is something wrong with your design.

Comment: please avoid short form of english

Comment: Api was designed by Java - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html.

Comment: please mention the complete reference as what do u mean by' API was designed by JAVA'